# jquery scrollTop not working on chrome -webkit-

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, web, webkit

so am making a website that when the scrollTop value reaches 450 it ill show some side-links and a floating header now that works fine on Firefox but in chrome it don't ! i tried different solutions from questions i found here but none of them worked !

i tried to add all the content to a wrapper div and change the jquery.scroll code selector from body to .wrapper -didn't work-

i tried adding this line of code to my jquery

```
 $("html").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow"); // also tried changing to body and so on
```

am felling this problem is from my CSS which i have these rules

```
html,body{
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

sadly when i remove one of these rules the scrolling don't work on FireFox and also it wont work on Chrome or any webkit browser

my jquery code for the scrolling is

```
$(" body ").scroll(function () {
var scrollVal = $(" body ").scrollTop();

if (scrollVal > 450) {
    $(".sn-links-srz").addClass("scroll-sn-show");
    $("#global-nav").css("display", "block");
}
else {
    $(".sn-links-srz").removeClass("scroll-sn-show");
    $("#global-nav").css("display", "none");
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just select them both => `$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: x }, options)`.

**EDIT:**
This is what I've used on another website:

```
var win = $(window),
    body = $(document.body);

win.scroll(function () {
    var scroll = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

    // header correction
    body.toggleClass(cfg.scrolledClass, scroll < 90);

    // performance boost
    body.addClass(cfg.scrollingClass); // css: pointer-events: none

    // provide a throttling class
    self.fn.delayedEvent(function () {
        body.removeClass(cfg.scrollingClass);
    }, 300, 'scrolling');
});
```

To apply the above example to your code I would rewrite it to:

```
var links = $(".sn-links-srz"),
    nav = $("#global-nav");

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scrollVal = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
        isScrolled = scrollVal > 450;

    links.toggleClass("scroll-sn-show", isScrolled);
    if (isScrolled){
        nav.show();
    } else {
        nav.hide();
    }
});
```

It's important performance wise, to cache as many variables as you can outside the scope of this function. As scrolling happens at rapid speeds there's no use in selecting your variables again and again.

With a ".scrolled" CSS class, as you did for the links, you can refactor the if else structure out too and just use `nav.toggleClass('scrolled', isScrolled)`instead.

If you would use the same ".scrolled" class in CSS for the nav and the links or whatever comes afterwards you can then do `nav.add(links).toggleClass('scrolled', isScrolled)`

Comment: Does it work when you click the arrow on the banner on [this](http://www.connections.be/en/tours) very website?

Comment: Am not tring to do any kind of scrolling animation

Comment: I want to show a header after the user gets to a certain place in the page

Comment: It's just that the scrollTop value on webkit browsers stays 0 i think or its just not getting updated due to something in the CSS

Comment: So please try `var scrollVal = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;`

Comment: Yet, it didn't work i will look through all of my CSS to find the problem

Comment: If you inspect the required HTML elements (F12) and see the classes change while scrolling then at least the JavaScript part is working. I can't think of anything CSS related to be honest unless your elements and classes don't match.

Comment: none worked 
i decided to let go on jquery and use pure javascript 

window.onscroll = function (event) 
{
    if(this.scrollY > 1000)
    {
        alert('Worked');
    }
}

this code worked fine on all browsers am targeting

Comment: You probably forgot to wrap it inside a DOM ready event? => `$(function(){/*copy/paste here*/});`. Perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

try using `document` instead of `body`:

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
var scrollVal = $(document).scrollTop();

if (scrollVal > 450) {
    $(".sn-links-srz").addClass("scroll-sn-show");
    $("#global-nav").css("display", "block");
}
else {
    $(".sn-links-srz").removeClass("scroll-sn-show");
    $("#global-nav").css("display", "none");
}

});
```

also if you want to scroll to top try animating both `html` and `body` like this:

```
$("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
```